# How to get executable path of 64 bit process in c#?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to get executable path of  process. I could use class Process to get executable path of local 32 bit process, and use WMI to get path of 32 bit process of remote PC.

Both of all get path rightly. But, I can't get path of 64 bit process. Does 64 bit process can't have executable path ?

addition: my computer is  64-bit machine.      .

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getexecutingassembly(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: It will help if your .NET app is running as 64-bit, instead of 32-bit WoW.

Comment: Not clear what is being asked - the "remote process" part makes it clear it is not from within the assembly and the OP spends quite some brainpower into not providing any sensible explanation what he tries to do actually.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is about getting the executable's path from within the same application, you can try `Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);`.

If you want to get the path for a 64 bit process from a 32 bit application, this may not be possible easily as described in this article: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/22075